# Use of UISearchController causes objc_weak_error

Tags: ios, swift

After adding an UISearchController to a UITableViewController, the following objc_weak_error is logged every time the app goes to to the background (by hitting the home button) if the "Malloc Scribble" Diagnostics option is activated in the Run Scheme.

> objc[8426]: __weak variable at 0x... holds 0x5555555555555555 instead
>   of 0x.... This is probably incorrect use of objc_storeWeak() and
>   objc_loadWeak(). Break on objc_weak_error to debug.

Setting the suggested breakpoint unfortunately does not provide helpful information.

I have faced this issue in a larger project, so I tried to reproduce it on a very simple app based on the "Single View App" template (xcode 10.1) with an UITableViewController embedded in a Navigation Controller with the following code. After performing a search, going to the background by hitting the home button will always trigger the error.
I was not able to find any useful information about this issue neither on stackoverflow nor on the web.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let data = ["Berlin", "London", "New York", "Paris", "Tokyo"]
    var filteredData = [String]()
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Candies"
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        definesPresentationContext = true
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return isFiltering() ? filteredData.count : data.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = isFiltering() ? filteredData[indexPath.row] : data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func searchBarIsEmpty() -> Bool {
        return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
    }

    func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
        filteredData = data.filter { $0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())}
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func isFiltering() -> Bool {
        return searchController.isActive && !searchBarIsEmpty()
    }
}

extension TableViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!)
    }
}
```

Is the error a result of a wrong usage of UISearchController in the code above or is this an iOS bug?
Or can it just be ignored?

Comment: Have you got any solution facing same kind of issue when I pop any viewController and press home button.